Cancelling a search running in a separate thread (chess engine)
I'm currently working on my chess engine in C#, Unity. My engine runs a search in a separate thread, so the Unity main thread works fine while calculating. To stop my engine from calculating too long, I made a time-out function. This function sets the 'cancellationRequested' flag to true, and my engine has to stop all the processes if the flag is true.
However, my engine seems to break randomly and does not stop the search process after receiving the cancellation flag. I cannot figure out how this happens, because I don't think there is any chance that it avoids all the cancellation checks. (I added some Debug.Log to figure out where the bug happens, but I could not.)
Here is the entire code for my engine and related stuff.
// EnginePlayer.cs

using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public static class EnginePlayer
{
    public static Board board;
    public static MoveMaker moveMaker;
    static Engine engine;
    public static bool isSearching = false;
    static bool cancelled = false;
    static CancellationTokenSource searchTimer;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        board = Main.mainBoard;
        engine = Main.engine;
    }

    public static void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log(engine.IsSearching() + " | " + engine.cancellationRequested);
        }

        // Get Engine Moves
        if (Graphic.isInMatch && 
        ((EngineSettings.enableWhiteEngine && board.isWhiteTurn) || (EngineSettings.enableBlackEngine && !board.isWhiteTurn)))
        {
            if (EngineSettings.useThreading)
            {
                if (!isSearching)
                {
                    RequestSearch();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SingleThreadedSearch();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SearchFinished()
    {
        Debug.Log("EnginePlayer Search Finished Signal");

        if (!cancelled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Search Not Cancelled - Call Get Best Move");
            GetBestMove();
        }

        isSearching = false;
        cancelled = false;

        Debug.Log("-----");
    }

    public static void CancelSearch()
    {
        cancelled = true;

        EndSearch();
    }

    public static void EndSearch()
    {
        engine?.TimeOut();
        searchTimer?.Cancel();
        
        isSearching = false;
    }

    static void RequestSearch()
    {
        Debug.Log("EnginePlayer Request");
        // isSearching = true;
        // cancelled = false;

        // engine.BeforeThreadedSearch();

        ThreadingManager.RequestStartSearch();

        // Task.Factory.StartNew (() => engine.StartSearch(EngineSettings.searchDepth), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        
    }

    public static void SearchStarted()
    {
        Debug.Log("EnginePlayer Search Started Signal");

        isSearching = true;
        searchTimer = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Delay(EngineSettings.searchMs, searchTimer.Token).ContinueWith((t) => {TimeOutThreadedSearch();});
    }

    static void GetBestMove()
    {
        Move move = engine.GetMove();
        searchTimer.Cancel();
            
        PlayMove(move);
    }

    static void SingleThreadedSearch()
    {
        engine.StartSearch(EngineSettings.searchDepth);
        Move move = engine.GetMove();
            
        PlayMove(move);
    }

    static void PlayMove(Move move)
    {
        if (move.moveValue != 0)
        {
            Graphic.grabbedPieceObject = moveMaker.FindPieceObject(move.startSquare);

            moveMaker.MakeGraphicalMove(move, true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Null Move Returned");
        }
    }

    static void TimeOutThreadedSearch()
    {
        engine?.TimeOut();
    }
}

// ThreadingManager.cs

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public static class ThreadingManager
{
    static bool searchStarted = false;
    static bool searchFinished = false;
    static bool startSearchRequested = false;
    static bool positionLoadingRequested = false;

    static void ThreadedSearch()
    {
        // SearchStarted();
        searchStarted = true;

        Main.engine.StartSearch(EngineSettings.searchDepth);

        // SearchFinished();
        searchFinished = true;
    }

    public static void RequestStartSearch()
    {
        Debug.Log("Threading REQ");

        if (startSearchRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        startSearchRequested = true;
        
        Debug.Log("Threading Rq St");
        Task.Factory.StartNew (() => ThreadedSearch(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public static void RequestPositionLoading()
    {
        if (positionLoadingRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Not searching
        if (!Main.engine.IsSearching())
        {
            Main.positionLoader.AfterEngineCancelled();
            return;
        }

        positionLoadingRequested = true;

        EnginePlayer.CancelSearch();
    }

    // Called outside of the main thread
    // public static void SearchFinished()
    // {
    //     searchFinished = true;
    // }

    // public static void SearchStarted()
    // {
    //     searchStarted = true;
    // }

    // Main thread
    public static void Update()
    {
        if (searchStarted)
        {
            EnginePlayer.SearchStarted();
            // if (startSearchRequested)
            // {
                
            //     startSearchRequested = false;
            // }

            startSearchRequested = false;
            searchStarted = false;
        }

        if (searchFinished)
        {
            EnginePlayer.SearchFinished();

            if (positionLoadingRequested)
            {
                Main.positionLoader.AfterEngineCancelled();
                positionLoadingRequested = false;
            }


            searchFinished = false;
        }
    }
}

// Engine.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Engine
{
    Board board;
    public TranspositionTable tt;

    readonly int ttSize = EngineSettings.ttSize;

    public Move bestMove;
    bool isSearching;
    public bool cancellationRequested;


    public Engine()
    {
        board = Main.mainBoard;
        tt = new TranspositionTable(board, ttSize);
        isSearching = false;
        cancellationRequested = false;
    }

    public void StartSearch(int maxDepth)
    {
        Debug.Log("Engine StartSearch");
        isSearching = true; 
        cancellationRequested = false;

        bestMove = MoveGen.GenerateMoves(board)[0];

        // Return Null Move
        if (maxDepth <= 0)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            // Iterative Deepening
            for (int depth = 1; depth <= maxDepth; depth++)
            {
                Debug.Log("Starting Iteration " + depth);

                int evalThisIteration = Search(depth, Infinity.negativeInfinity, Infinity.positiveInfinity, 0);

                if (cancellationRequested)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Engine Cancel - ITERATIVE BREAK | DEPTH " + depth);
                    break;
                }

                if (Evaluation.IsMateScore(evalThisIteration))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        EndSearch();
        Debug.Log("Engine EndSearch");
    }

    int Search(int depth, int alpha, int beta, int plyFromRoot)
    {
        if (cancellationRequested)
        {
            Debug.Log("Engine Cancel - HEAD | DEPTH " + depth);
            return 0;
        }

        // Try looking up the current position in the transposition table.
        // If the same position has already been searched to at least an equal depth
        // to the search we're doing now,we can just use the recorded evaluation.
        if (plyFromRoot != 0)
        {
            int ttVal = tt.LookupEvaluation (depth, plyFromRoot, alpha, beta);
            if (ttVal != TranspositionTable.lookupFailed)
            {
                // The Transposition Table cannot store the repetition data, 
                // so whenever a position is repeated, the engine ends up in a threefold draw.
                // To prevent that, check if it's threefold once again!
                // For simplicity, just check if previous position is already reached
                if (board.positionHistory[board.currentZobristKey] > 1)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                Move move = tt.GetStoredMove ();

                if (plyFromRoot == 0)
                {
                    bestMove = move;
                }

                return ttVal;
            }
        }

        if (depth == 0)
        {
            return QuiescenceSearch(alpha, beta);
        }

        List<Move> legalMoves = MoveGen.GenerateMoves(board);

        MateChecker.MateState mateState = MateChecker.GetPositionState(board, legalMoves);
        if (mateState != MateChecker.MateState.None)
        {
            if (mateState == MateChecker.MateState.Checkmate)
            {
                return -Evaluation.checkmateEval + plyFromRoot;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        MoveOrder.GetOrderedList(legalMoves);

        int evalType = TranspositionTable.UpperBound;

        foreach (Move move in legalMoves)
        {
            board.MakeMove(move);

            int eval = -Search(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, plyFromRoot + 1);

            board.UnmakeMove(move);

            if (cancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.Log("Engine Cancel - Body | DEPTH " + depth);
                return 0;
            }

            if (eval >= beta)
            {
                tt.StoreEvaluation (depth, plyFromRoot, beta, TranspositionTable.LowerBound, move);
                return beta;
            }

            if (eval > alpha)
            {
                alpha = eval;
                evalType = TranspositionTable.Exact;
                
                if (plyFromRoot == 0)
                {
                    bestMove = move;
                }
            }

            tt.StoreEvaluation (depth, plyFromRoot, alpha, evalType, bestMove);

            // if (plyFromRoot == 0 && cancellationRequested)
            // {
            //     break;
            // }
        }

        return alpha;
    }

    int QuiescenceSearch(int alpha, int beta)
    {
        // if (cancellationRequested)
        // {
        //     return alpha;
        // }
        if (cancellationRequested)
        {

            Debug.Log("QSEARCH HEAD");
            return 0;
        }

        int ttVal = tt.LookupEvaluation (0, 0, alpha, beta);
        if (ttVal != TranspositionTable.lookupFailed)
        {
            return ttVal;
        }

        int standPat = Evaluation.Evaluate(board);

        if (standPat >= beta)
        {
            return beta;
        }
        if (alpha < standPat)
        {
            alpha = standPat;
        }

        List<Move> moves = MoveGen.GenerateMoves(board, true);
        MoveOrder.GetOrderedList(moves);

        foreach (Move move in moves)
        {
            board.MakeMove(move);

            int eval = -QuiescenceSearch(-beta, -alpha);

            board.UnmakeMove(move);

            if (eval >= beta)
            {
                return beta;
            }
            if (eval > alpha)
            {
                alpha = eval;
            }
        }

        return alpha;
    }

    public Move GetMove()
    {
        return bestMove;
    }

    void EndSearch()
    {
        isSearching = false;
        cancellationRequested = true;
    
        // AfterThreadedSearch();
    }

    public void TimeOut()
    {
        Debug.Log("TimeOut");
        cancellationRequested = true;
    }


    public bool IsSearching()
    {
        return isSearching;
    }

    void AfterThreadedSearch()
    {
        // ThreadingManager.SearchFinished();
    }
}

Plus, I got a screenshot of the debug logs right after the bug occurred:

As you can see, after the "TimeOut" log, the engine seems to be stuck somewhere. It doesn't even send logs such as "EnginePlayer Search Finished Signal".
My question is, there is absolutely no way that the engine got stuck without even a single prepared log message. I cannot find where it happens. Also, this bug just happens randomly while doing an engine vs engine match.
I tried to figure out where my code went wrong, and I couldn't get anything.

Best way of debugging is in Visual Studio and use Debug : Break All.  Then look at the trace stack to see where code is stuck.

Protip: add precondition asserts to your methods.

@jdweng Is there a way to store the debugging process and check it later after the program is done? Because I can't just add a breakpoint at Engine.cs, StartSearch() since this does not happen consistently.

You have to wait for issue to occur than stop app using the Break All.  Only way to ensure you get stack trace when issue occurs.  Saving trace will not tell you when issue occurs.

IMHO create a CancellationTokenSource and pass in a CancellationToken per call instead of trying to fiddle with your bool cancellationRequested in a thread safe way.

@JeremyLakeman As you can see, the task is a giant recursive function. Will it still work with recursive tasks?

Just keep passing the CancellationToken struct deeper. Then you can throw a OperationCanceledException to unwind the stack.

Use Coroutines!!
Use the
 StopCoroutine(string methodName);

To stop the coroutine from running.
Use a for loop to create stages for your coroutine if you need to. Iterate though your stages using a switch statement and yeilding. In the default of the switch call the stop coroutine.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html
